# Scrolling is not detected in the area where the clipped Image is in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'd like to place the tappable Image over the ScrollView in SwiftUI. Now I'm trying the following code but there is an issue. The image is clipped and tapping only happens on the Image as expected. However, the scrolling (which means drag gesture?) is not detected on the area where the clipped area of the image is. If I remove `.scaledToFill()` it starts working as expected though.

Is there any workaround?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(1..<100) {
                        Text("\($0)")
                    }
                }
            }

            Button {
                print(Date())
            } label: {
                Image("theme_background")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    .border(.black)
                    .clipped()
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: try to assign frame of button

Comment: @Jatin Thanks, but it doesn't still work

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.allowsHitTesting(false)` to the `Image(...)` after `.contentShape(Rectangle())`, to have the scrolling detected in the area where the clipped Image is.

Comment: I was looking for a way to propagate the touch event to the scroll view and this is really what I wanted. Thank you!